# c++ copy assignment syntax comparison - which is better?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I am studying C++ at University, and in the break I am going through Strousrtup's "The CPP Programming Language 4th Edition" to fill in the gaps of my understanding and what we are being taught in class.

In section 3.3.1 he details a code snippet for a simplified version of a vector class (which is type-specific to doubles only):

```
Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& a) {
    double* p = new double[a.sz]; 
    for (int i=0; i!=a.sz; ++i)
        p[i] = a.elem[i]; 
    delete[] elem;
    elem = p;
    sz = a.sz;
    return *this;
}
```

Now, I had already written my own version of an overridden copy assignment operator to go along with this simplified quasi-vector before I saw this, which seems to work correctly, but I was wondering, is there anything wrong with deleting the memory allocated that `elem` points to and then re-initialising it, as I do below, compared to how Stroustrup does it?

```
vectoR& vectoR::operator=(const vectoR& v) {
    delete[] elem;
    elem = new double[v.size()];
    sz = v.size();
    for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) 
        elem[i] = v[i];
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: That design would make your vector very unintuitive to any other C++ programmer who tried to pick up your code

Comment: @MattMcNabb to kill this irrelevant line of thought I will make the condition of the for-loop consistent with Stroustrup's formatting. These comments are not pertinent to the question being asked.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I have so much to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is incorrect, and has undefined behavior.  What
happens if `new double[v.size()]` throws an exception?

In general, you shouldn't do anything which can invalidate an
object until after you've done everything which might throw and
exception.  Leaving a point to deleted memory results in an
invalid object, that `new` can always throw, so you shouldn't
delete `elem` until after you've done the `new`.

EDIT:

To be more explicit: from the original poster's suggested
implementation:

```
delete[] elem;
elem = new double[v.size()];
```

The first line invalidates the pointer `elem`, and if there is
an exception in the second line (and `new` can always throw an
exception), then the assignment operator leaves the object with
the invalid pointer; any further access to this pointer,
including in the destructor of the object, is undefined
behavior.

There are, in fact, many ways of avoiding this problem in this
particular instance:

```
delete[] elem;
elem = nullptr;
elem = new double[v.size()];
```

for example (provided that any functions called on the object
can deal with a null pointer), or (what is effectively the same
thing):

```
delete[] elem;
elem = new (std::nothrow) double[v.size()];
if ( elem == nullptr )
    throw std::bad_alloc();
```

Both of these solutions are in many ways special, however, and
not generally applicable.  They also leave the object in
a special state, which may require extra handling.  The
usual solution is to do anything that can throw before modifying
any of the state of the object.  In this case, the only thing
which can throw is the `new`, and we end up with Stroustrup's
solution.  In more complicated objects, the necessary solution
may be more complicated; one common simple solution is the swap
idiom:

```
MyType& MyType::operator=( MyType const& other )
{
    MyType tmp( other );    //  Copy constructor
    swap( tmp );            //  Member function, guaranteed nothrow
    return *this;
}
```

This works well *if* you can write a nonthrow swap member
function.  You often can, because swapping pointers is a nothrow
(so in this case, all swap would do is swap `elem`), but it is
not a given.  Each case needs to be evaluated individually.

The swap idiom does give the "strong" guarantee: either the
assignment fully succeeds, or the object's state is unchanged.
You don't often need this guarantee, however; it's usually
sufficient that the object be in some coherent state (so that it
can be destructed).

Finally: if your class has several resources, you'll almost
certainly want to encapsulate them in some sort of RAII class
(e.g. smart pointer) or in separate base classes, so that you
can make the constructors exception safe, so that they won't
leak the first resource if allocating the second fails.  This
can be a useful technique even in cases where there is only one
resource; in the original example, if `elem` had been an
`std::unique_ptr<double[]>`, no delete would have been necessary
in the assignment operator, and just:

```
elem = new double[v.size()];
//  copy...
```

is all that would be needed.  In practice, if real code, cases
where this solves the solution are fairly rare; in real code,
for example, the orginal problem would be solved with
`std::vector<double>` (and the requirements of `std::vector` are
such that `std::unique_ptr` is not really a solution).  But they
do exist, and classes like `std::unique_ptr` (or an even simpler
scoped pointer) are certainly a solution worth having in your
toolkit.

Comment: I would check this as an answer, except that it's not explicit enough for someone who is learning to know exactly what to do to correct/prevent the problems you describe. I think I understand what you mean, but could you provide some correct(ed) code to back it up?

Comment: thanks, checked it as answered. I appreciate the extra detail, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Strousrtup's way is self-assignment safe. That is, an instance can be assigned to itself

```
a = a;
```

Once you've finished that book you may want to scoot through Meyer's "Effective C++" (2005) which is also an excellent text and considers such problems as these.

Comment: That's the straightforward answer I was looking for! I will mark it as answered once it lets me in ten minutes. Thank you!

Comment: You might notice exception safety, too

Comment: +1 I love clear answers like this. And reading Stroustrup is an excellent idea.

Comment: @DieterLücking can you expand upon your comment about exception safety in Stroustrup's code? Just to make sure I understand...

Comment: @BenjaminR If an exception occurs during building the new data, the old data stays intact and will not be altered.

Comment: Given that `a = a;` is possible, wouldn't it be wise to make the function start with `if ( &a == this ) return *this;` to avoid wasting  a lot of time?

Comment: If you look at the chapter in Stroustrup's book on exceptions, he uses vector as an example and goes through it in more detail on efficiency and exception safety.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's true... but an even better solution can be found in the top answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Comment: @Matt That would be considered premature pessimization. Self-assignment is very rare so it would be unwise to optimize this case, while burdening the normal case. Self-assignment needs to be correct, but it doesn't have to be fast.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It's easy to protect against self assignment; the real problem here is that your implementation is incorrect even without self assignment.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You could, but... the function remains incorrect.  In general, if you think you have to test for self-assignment, there's a good chance that your implementation is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Stroustrup's implementation will not destroy the existing elem if an exception occurs, and allows self-assignment.